# How does the CAN bus handle remote frame conflicts?

Tags: can

The right to send specific data frames on the CAN bus belongs uniquely to one node, but remote frames don't seem to have this limitation, so it seems that a bus conflict occurs when more than one node requests the same data frame at the same time (arbitration can't come up with a result), and what happens on the bus at that point?

Comment: I've removed the `canopen` tag, since this question is CAN in general, and is not CANopen-specific.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that a bus conflict occurs when more than one node requests the same data frame at the same time

Not really.

It is fine for multiple bus nodes to send the same Remote Frame. The CAN arbitration allows multiple nodes to arbitrate with same arbitration field, as long as there is no data field. Since Remote Frames cannot have a data field (by definition), it's fine for multiple nodes to request the same data by sending the same Remote Frame at the same time.

Now, any response to a Remote Frame will be a Data Frame, and regular rules for Data Frames apply. The nodes on the bus must be configured such that no two nodes can send a Data Frame with the same arbitration ID. *This applies independently of what triggered the transmission!* Data Frame transmissions requested by Remote Frames are no different than those triggered internally by the node (e.g. on a periodic schedule), or in response to a regular Data Frame.

Basically, the Remote Frame is a special exception to the Data Frame arbitration rules, and allows *potentially multiple nodes to request the same data*. Since the data is transmitted in a Data Frame, there still can only be one node allowed to send such a Data Frame, per arbitration rules.

Comment: Keep in mind that RTR frames do have the DLC field however, which like the RTR bit is also part of the arbitration process. The higher layer protocol may specify if the DLC should be set to any particular size or if it doesn't matter.